# Google Drive link parameter to hint which account (email) to access with

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to construct a link to a Google Drive file and specify the email account to access the file as? I know that it is possible to use `/u/1` or `/u/2` in the path, but I am looking at generating a link to send to users who own multiple Google accounts, and I want to make it easy for them to access the file with the account which has read/write access, as opposed to accessing with an account which has readonly access.

I think I have seen something like `https://drive.google.com/open?id=123882182828&email=user@example.com` but cannot recall where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `authuser` parameter can take both the number which is used in the `/u/` part of the path, or an email address. So, appending this query parameter: `authuser=email@example.com` will make google drive use this account, **if it is in the list of signed in accounts**.

E.g., `https://drive.google.com/open?id=123882182828&authuser=user@example.com`

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `authuser` parameter doesn't work anymore. Please tell me if I'm mistaken; I would love to be mistaken.

Comment: @Merchako still works, I tried it just now and it seems you can also add it also works if you append it to a `docs.google.com/document/d/8383838383838388338?authuser=...` url.

Comment: The example you gave is for Google Docs. Could you confirm that is also works for Google Drive, @chutz?

Comment: Yes @Merchako both work. Again, this only works if you are already logged in with that account.

Here are a few links you can try for yourself.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aNxfHeb51KIPIpD6PtAQzxUNHuAwdeNhYOqWHJ8wipw/edit?authuser=user@gmail.com
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aNxfHeb51KIPIpD6PtAQzxUNHuAwdeNhYOqWHJ8wipw/edit?authuser=user@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you, @chutz. For some reason, I've been getting unpredictable behavior for searches when using the forms `https://drive.google.com/drive/search?authuser=name@example.com&q={query}` and `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/name@example.com/search?q={query}`. I suspect this is a problem with my browser preserving my logins rather than the URLs.